# ASP.NET 5 IIS 500 error with EF7 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am hosting an application in IIS 8 which is developed in ASP.NET 5, MVC 6, and EF7. I have created API for the application which is accessible via `http://localhost/api` and I have created few controllers to access data.

When I access the API from visual studio everything works fine, and I able to retrieve JSON data back. But when I host the application IIS 8 and browser `localhost/api/controller`, I get `500` error in IIS logs. I also have `http platform handler 1.2` installed on windows server 2012 r2 server. I am actually able to browse static pages and other links like `localhost/home`, but when I try to access api controller I get 500 error code back.

Now when I use execute `web.cmd` file from the application to self host the application and browse `localhost:5000/api/controller`, I am able to retrieve json data back, but not from IIS hosted site.

Since I dont know what is the problem, I enabled `Failed request tracing rules` and I was able to capture logs with 500 error. Below is the screenshot:

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: did you have this line in your Startup class: `app.UseIISPlatformHandler();` ?

Comment: yup that is in there and I am able to browse the application home page and not `api/controller`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not getting this from your failed request logs, but might I suggest the usual suspects since you say it works outside of IIS:

1. Confirm that the App Pool is set to work with .NET 5.0 and isn't set to a different CLR like 2.0 or 4.0. (*Actually strike this, since non-API MVC controllers wouldn't have worked at all in that case...*)
2. Confirm that the App Pool is running with an Account that has sufficient database permissions if using NTLM security with SQL, since the execution context may be different when running IIS Express from Visual Studio versus IIS.

I would also suggest checking the Windows Error logs, not just request trace....

Comment: Currently the app pool is set to `No Manage code` CLR version. I am also hard coding connection string in startup.cs file for SQL connection as it doesnt use windows service account to make connection. Should I still set app pool identity to a service account or local system? I didnt find any errors in eventlogs and that is the reason I opened up this issue here. :(

Comment: Actually No Manage Code appears right for ASP.NET 5 according to this: http://www.strathweb.com/2015/12/running-asp-net-5-website-on-iis/    One thing you can look for in the IIS logs is a subcode for the 500 error, sometimes that has more info.  The link above references some possible 500 errors...

Comment: I would try setting app pool account to your user temporarily to see if that changed matters...since you are likely to have more than sufficient permissions...for prod I'd create a service account.

Comment: Yeah, I also tried that link as well. I dont think I am facing application problem. My guess is http platform handler is unable to route api request correctly.

Comment: Alright, the service account seems to worked! :) I wonder why it required me to set service account to access API as with application identity it is allowing me to access other MVC pages.